# How to read the bind operator ">>=" in words?

Tags: haskell, monads

When reading code, I like to be able to form sentences in my head. For example, `x <- getChar` could be something like "x slurps getChar". Or `a . b` would be "b applied to a".

But when it comes to the Monadic Bind operator `f >>= g`, I just leave a mental gap in the sentence in my head, because I don't know how to read it.
I thought about "f binds g", but that feels wrong. What suggestions do you have?

The proposed duplicate link contains some really nice answers for other operators, but for the bind operator the answers just say "bind". However, "f bind g" doesn't seem meaningful to me.

Comment: In some sense, it depends on the specific monad in question, but reading bind as “and then” tends to work alright. Of course, both your “correct” examples are somewhat wrong, since `x <- getChar` is no different from `getChar >>= \x -> ...` and `a . b` is composition, not application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there pronounceable names for common Haskell operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894/are-there-pronounceable-names-for-common-haskell-operators)

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for that "possible duplicate" link! it is really helpful but it seems to me that for the bind operator, it does not offer a good answer. I'll try to explain why I think so in an edit :)

Comment: @AlexisKing I like your proposal "and then". What do you mean is wrong about my example with getChar?

Comment: Words and concepts are related.  How would you rate your understanding of monad as a concept?  It may be that "f bind g" will start feeling more meaningful as you get more comfortable in your understanding.

Comment: @luqui I've been studying the concept of Applicative Functors and Monads only since last week, so you may be right. I believe I understand what the bind operator does, but as the content of the Monad `f` is "put" into the function `g`, it feels more intuitive to me that "g binds f". But reading from right to left is probably not the best solution

Comment: maybe you're right and I can just try to use `f bind g` until it becomes a meaningful word for me

Comment: I definitely wouldn't read `a . b` as “`b` applied to `a`”. That would be `b a`. It's just _`a` composed with `b`_, or perhaps _`a` after `b`_.

Comment: [There](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pronunciation) is a page on haskellwiki about pronuncation.

Comment: @leftaroundabout what would you say to "the result of b applied to a"?

Comment: The other way around, _`a` applied to the result of `b`_. But that would mean there are actually _values_ around, i.e. it would more correspond to `a $ b x`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh, yes I see my mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: I have recently seen someone suggest "`f` from `x`" for `f =<< x`. I kind of like it, though I can't quite see an analogue for `>>=` which wouldn't be annoyingly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest thinking of the word 'bind' in the sense of 'attach': binding `g` to `f` means *attaching* a monadic action `g` to the monad `f`. To flesh this out a bit, think of `f`, a monad, as a computation which, when run, will return some value (call this value `x`). Binding a monadic action `g` to a monad `f` expresses a new computation in which the monadic action `g` is now *attached* to the monad `f`, in the sense that the result (`x`) of the monadic computation `f` is to be passed along as an argument to the action `g`, which in turn returns a new (monadic) computation.

Comment: [1/2] This makes intuitive sense, though the terminology is a bit backwards with respect to how we usually call things in Haskell. It is better to call the `f` in `f >>= g` a "monadic value", "computation" or "action", and not  "monad" -- the monad proper is the type constructor and/or its `Monad` instance. As for the `g` function, there is "Kleisli arrow" if you want a specific term, but simply "the `a -> m b` function" will work fine in most contexts.

Comment: [2/2] The "bind" name reflects that in `f >>= \x -> g x` (i.e. `do { x <- f; g x }`) we bind the result(s) of `f` to the variable `x`, so that we can refer to it in what follows.

Comment: @duplode I agree w/ everything you said. Re your second comment: yes, the term 'bind' is so named b/c of the variable binding going on in your example above, and that would go a long way toward explaining reading `x <- f` as `x` is bound to the result of `f`, but there's still some cognitive disconnect b/t understanding that, and understanding `f >>= g` as `f` bind `g`.

Answer (score 2):

Names of `>>=` for monad-like constructs of other languages:

- For Javascript [promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/coming-from-other-languages.html#haskell), it is `then`. (Not a perfect correspondence though, because `then` does more things.)
- For Java [Optionals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), it is `flatMap` (They are similarly named functions, but they don't come from the same interface.)
- For Java's [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), it is `thenComposeAsync`.

`>>=` is equivalent to first mapping with an effectful function

```
fmap putStrLn getLine :: IO (IO ())
```

and then "fusing" the two nested layers of the type constructor with `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`:

```
join (fmap putStrLn getLine) :: IO ()
```

So how about calling it "map 'n fuse"?

Comment: As another data point, LINQ [calls it `SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx), which makes sense in context (its `fmap` analogue is called `Select`) but isn't very illuminating for our purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Elm uses `andThen` which is equivalent to `>>=`

```
makeThingA >>= (\a -> consumeThing a)
```

aka

```
makeThingA `andThen` (\a -> consumeThing a)
```