# <$ in Maybe definition

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> (fmap . const ) 2 Just 3
2
Prelude> 2 <$ Just 3
Just 2
Prelude> :t (<$)
(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a
Prelude> :t fmap . const
fmap . const :: Functor f => b -> f a -> f b
```

in functor,

```
(<$)        =  fmap . const
```

why I get different result for Maybe? did not find a implement of `<$` in Maybe. Thanks.

Comment: `( (<$>) . const ) 2 Just 3` = `(const 2 <$> Just) 3` is *not* in `Maybe`, but in `((->) r)`, where `fmap = (.)` so it becomes `(const 2 . Just) 3 = const 2 (Just 3)`. `2 <$ Just 3 = fmap (const 2) (Just 3) = Just ( (const 2) 3)`.

Answer (score 6):

`(fmap . const) 2 Just 3` is equivalent to `((fmap . const) 2 Just) 3`, where `2 <$ Just` is `const 2` and `const 2 3` is `2`.

You meant:

```
(fmap . const) 2 $ Just 3
```

Comment: Is there a common name for this function (`<$`)? Maybe `constMap`?

Comment: @ftor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894/are-there-pronounceable-names-for-common-haskell-operators

Comment: `2 <$ Just` is `const 2 . Just`.

Comment: @WillNess: … which is `const 2`.

Comment: skipping of derivation steps belongs in scientific papers, not in textbooks. :)

Comment: @WillNess: It’s not a derivation. It’s a simplification of parts of the expression at a time so the OP can follow what’s happening.

Comment: skipping of simplification steps belongs in scientific papers, not in textbooks.

Comment: @WillNess: It’s not a textbook. My answer also uses the RyanHC implementation where `Functor ((->) r)` has `x <$ _ = const x`.

Comment: SO answers are addressed to newcomers, as textbooks are.

Comment: @WillNess: Cool. Still not a textbook despite potentially sharing a target audience, and this remains exactly the answer I would give a newcomer.

Comment: then they wd still have hard time following it.

Comment: @WillNess: No, I’m pretty sure addressing it at a semantic level rather than “expand the GHC implementation” is easier to follow. I’ll be happy to add words on the former if a newcomer asks. :)

Comment: the ["default definition `fmap . const`"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-) looks like a semantic level definition, and the ["RyanHC implementation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833632/in-maybe-definition/44833660?noredirect=1#comment77755703_44833660) looks like a specific implementation, a clever shortcut, to me. (what is RyanHC BTW?) --- of course *" `2 <$ Just` is `const 2`"* on its own is completely baffling to me, that's why I commented in the first place. I can't understand it except by filling in the missing step.

Comment: @WillNess: Different people have different intuitive explanations I guess :)

Comment: yes, some are comfortable with skipping steps, some are not. experts more among the first group, newbies the second.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you typed `(fmap . const) 2 Just 3`. I believe what you meant was rather `(fmap . const) 2 (Just 3)`. In the former, the function `fmap . const` is applied to three arguments, namely `2`, `Just` and `3`, and, in the latter, your expression is indeed equivalent to `2 <$ Just 3`.

```
> (fmap . const) 2 (Just 3)
Just 2
> 2 <$ Just 3
Just 3
```