# Implementing an extra title bar button

Tags: c++, button, titlebar

I am developing a C++ Desktop application, and wondered what exactly I would need to do in order to add a button into the title bar of my application, and how to do it. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

I'm aiming to achieve something like the titlebar of the Windows File Explorer

[image]

or something like this

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Too broad, as you will need some library, for each library we have to teach you from the basic etc.

Comment: @user202729 What libraries would be suitable to perform this task? Could you link me to one? You don't necessarily need to teach the basics of them to me, I could do that myself ;) Thanks.

Comment: That way your question becomes a off-site resource recommendation which is off-topic. (but rarely off-topic questions can be useful for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894/are-there-pronounceable-names-for-common-haskell-operators))

Answer (score 0):

First one requires [Ribbon framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316910(v=vs.85).aspx), there is also MFC and some third-party variants.

Second is some sort of [Custom window frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx) implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll look into the Ribbon framework, though I was originally planning to do some kind of custom window frame implementation, but that looks very difficult for someone like myself to take on.