# The <* syntax in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I'm given the following code

```
 newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }

   instance Applicative Parser where
   pure a = Parser $ \s -> Just (a,s)
   f <*> a = Parser $ \s ->
     case parse f s of
       Just (g,s') -> parse (fmap g a) s'
       Nothing -> Nothing

    instance Alternative Parser where
      empty = Parser $ \s -> Nothing
      l <|> r = Parser $ \s -> parse l s <|> parse r s

    satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
    satisfy p = Parser f
       where f [] = Nothing
             f (x:xs) = if p x then Just (x,xs) else Nothing

    ws :: Parser ()
    ws = pure () <* many (satisfy isSpace)
```

I know that ws parser removes leading spaces. But I need an explanation how exactly this is done. I don't understand the `<*` syntax  ( I know `<*>`). Can some help me understand  the syntax and why it is working ?

Comment: `<*` is a variant of `<*>` that performs the first action, then the second, and returns the result of the first one. https://tech.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/operators

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746894/14955

Comment: But what function is get called  by   <*  ?  I have only <*> implemented

Comment: `<*` is an `Applicative` method with a default definition of `(<*) = liftA2 const`. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Applicative

Comment: And `liftA2` itself *also* has a default definition in terms of `(<*>)`, just as `(<*>)` has a default definition in terms of `liftA2`. Define *either* `(<*>)` or `liftA2` in your instance declaration (along with `pure`), and you have a complete definition for `(<*>)`, `liftA2`, `(<*)`, and `(*>)`.

Comment: you haven't included the definition of `isSpace`. also, in Haskell, indentation matters. all lines in the same scope must start from the same column in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

No fear! It's easy, when we go by *small steps*, and see where it leads us. Next time, try doing it yourself.

[`(<*) = liftA2 const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Applicative) and [`liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Applicative), so

```
ws :: Parser ()
ws = pure () <* many (satisfy isSpace) 
     = {- (<*) = liftA2 const -}
     liftA2 const (pure ()) (many $ satisfy isSpace) 
     = {- liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x) -}
     fmap const (pure ()) <*> many (satisfy isSpace)
     = {- by Applicative laws -}
     (pure const <*> pure ()) <*> many (satisfy isSpace)
     = {- by homomorphism law of Applicatives -}
     pure (const ()) <*> many (satisfy isSpace)
     = {- with Applicative Do -}
     do { f <- pure (const ())
        ; r <- many (satisfy isSpace)
        ; pure (f r) }
     = {- by Law of `pure` being the identity, i.e. no-op, effects-wise -}
     do { let f = const ()
        ; r <- many (satisfy isSpace)
        ; pure (f r) }
     = {- by substitution -}
     do { r <- many (satisfy isSpace)
        ; pure (const () r) }
     =
     do { _ <- many (satisfy isSpace)
        ; pure () }
     =
     do { many (satisfy isSpace)
        ; pure () }
     = {- Monad Comprehension illustration -}
     [ () | _ <- many (satisfy isSpace) ]
```

(with the Applicative Do notation; to get the feeling for what this does. The Applicative Laws are enumerated at the above link as well.)

So it does what `many (satisfy isSpace)` does, except the computed value it returns is always `()`.

In pure functions, `f a = ()` would completely ignore its second argument. We could call it as `f (1 / 0)` and it wouldn't care. But Applicative Functors express computations, and `<*>` combines computations fully known prior to the combination so that each one gets *performed*, whether its computed value is later used or not.

Comment: see also https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative